# How to resolve Manifest merger Failed error

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I am getting manifest merger failed error when i add elegeant number button library to my gradle files.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon
>   value=(@mipmap/app_logoo) from AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-41    is also
>   present at [com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.3]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-43 value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher).  Suggestion:
>   add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-56:19 to override.

I have tried adding all the versions of this library but none works

Answer (score 2):

As the suggestion in error says, you need to add `tools:replace="android:icon"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`. `tools:replace` means you want to replace the attribute value with your current attribute value in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

You can do it something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.yourapp">

  <application
      android:name=".YourApp"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      tools:replace="android:icon">

      <!-- code omitted here -->

   </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: But i removed my logoo from manifest file as well and that worked too... i have no idea why i was getting error from my logo

Comment: The error happens because android manifest merger tool will merge all of your `AndroidManifest.xml` from all the project and found there are already same attribute so it will complaining about it. So, you need to tell the tool to use only the attribute from your main module by replacing them. Hence you need to use `tools:replace`. Please read https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE :** Add this to your `build.gradle` and make sure you are using the same `versions as '26.0.2'` -

```
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
    DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '26.0.2'
         }
      }
    }
 }
```